# Umbraco 7.6.3 Tests to Controller always fails

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, nunit, umbraco7, surface-controller

I have a serious issue with testings on Umbraco 7.6.3 because my test always get the same error:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at DirectUmbraco.Models.ContactModel..ctor() in E:\Projects\Umbraco\DirectUmbraco\DirectUmbraco\Models\ContactModel.cs:line 13
   at DirectUmbraco.Tests.FormsControllerTests.TestContactMethod() in E:\Projects\Umbraco\DirectUmbraco\DirectUmbraco.Tests\ControllersTests.cs:line 43
```

line 43 refers to my ContactModel constructor (inherited from Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel ) and My Controllers are inherited from SurfaceController.

```
public ContactModel()
            :base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent){
        }
```

An this is my test method:

```
[Test]
        public void TestContactMethod()
        {
            var controller= new FormController(); //until this the test pass OK
            var contactModel = new ContactModel(); //Here the Exception is thrown
            var response = controller.Contact(contactModel);
            Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        }
```

I 've checked some [related](http://skrift.io/articles/archive/unit-testing-umbraco-with-umbraco-context-mock/) [content](http://blog.aabech.no/archive/the-basics-of-unit-testing-umbraco-just-got-simpler/) [here](http://blog.aabech.no/archive/the-basics-of-unit-testing-umbraco/) and [here too](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/37255-How-can-I-unit-test-a-class-inheriting-from-SurfaceController) but no one with lucky.
What can I do to solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't just create your controller because it needs tons of dependencies. Take a look at http://skrift.io/articles/archive/unit-testing-umbraco-with-umbraco-context-mock/

Comment: Sorry @MarioLopez but I try this to and didn't work for me, my controllers inherits form SurfaceController.

Comment: Read the article, you have to download a couple of Nuget packages and inherit your controller from BaseSurfaceController instead. This controller has the constructors so you can pass mock context.

Comment: @MarioLopez An the models? they inherits from Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel and give me too null reference exception with constructor  `:base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent){
        }`

Comment: Also the PublishedContentRequest of the mock is always null.

Comment: I honestly don't know where you are getting that issue. If you follow that aricle everything is very clear. What models are you talking about?

Comment: Hi @MarioLopez, my ContactModel inherits from `Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel` and the constructor looks like:
`public ContactModel()
            :base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent){
        }`
when I try to create my model instance or mock to pass it to the controller always get null ref exception and send me to the constructor. I use the approach [here](http://blog.aabech.no/archive/the-basics-of-unit-testing-umbraco-just-got-simpler/) to get it done and nothing, the same.

Comment: If you use the Gdev package, you have to inherit form BaseSurfaceController, then you pass a ContentMock and helper in the constructor. You don't have to pass your RenderModel to the controller but to the ActionMethods. Actually I don't think you can use Surface Controllers for this, you should use RenderMvcController. Are you trying to hijack the routes? : https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers

Comment: And the constructor for your ContactModel looks wrong, I don't think it should call that base. Where have you taken those instructions from?